# How to take different datatype as input in single line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to take string and int as input using single input line but interpreter returning me the  error `'type' object is not iterable`. Here is the code i tried:

```
name, age = map(str, int, input("Enter the name and age \t").split())
```

Comment: You are close, the error here is `map` usage.

Answer (score 1):

You were close, you can do the cast afterwards:

```
name, age = input("Enter the name and age \t").split()
age = int(age)
```

You are using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) incorrectly. If you really want to do it in one line you could have a lambda function like this:

```
name, age = map(lambda x: int(x) if x.isdigit() else x, input("Enter the name and age \t").split())
```

Comment: map with a lambda? just use a comprehension: `name, age = [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in input("Enter the name and age \t").split()]`

Comment: @wjandrea Just checked out and the lambda is faster than list comprehension (0.192 vs 0.449 microsecs)

Comment: Yeah, nothing really wrong with a lambda in a map, just a comprehension is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Don't overcomplicate things.

```
name, age = input("Enter the name and age\t").split()
age = int(age)
```

---

The problem is that `map` expects *one* callable, followed by one or more iterable values, depending on how many arguments the callable expects. The callable is applied to one element from each iterable, equivalent to

```
# result = list(map(f, x1, x2, ...))
result = [f(a1, a2, ...) for a1, a2, ... in zip(x1, x2, ...)]
```

What you want is multiple callables, each to be applied to a different element from a single iterable:

```
name, age = [f(a) for f, a in zip([str, int], xs)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name, age = [int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in input("Enter the name and age \t").split()]
```

NOTE:

> you cannot use `map` function on that way
>
> The **map() function** executes a specified function for each item in
>   a iterable. The item is sent to the function as a parameter.
>
> *Syntax*
>
> ```
> map(function, iterables)
> ```

Comment: You can create a lambda function. Check out my solution.

Comment: yes, I agree. but the function cannot be used in the way that OP is used it(I am taking about syntax)